# Date format does not display correctly until app is closed and reopened

Tags: delphi, date, sqlite, formatting, firedac

I am working on a simple database application in Delphi using FireDAC and SQLite3. Whenever I insert a new record into the database, the date format that is shown on my form is always in the format of `yyyy-mm-dd` and once I close and reopen the application the format changes to `m/d/yyyy` which is the format I was expecting and wish to always be displayed without closing and reopening my application.

The Definition Parameters and Options for the FireDAC connection are all at their default values. The DataType set for the field that holds the date in the SQLite3 database is set to `DATE`. Finally, the code I use to insert the record is below.

```
Qry.SQL.Text := 'INSERT INTO employees (HireDate) VALUES (:HiredOn)';

Qry.ParamByName('HiredOn').AsDate := DateTimePicker1.Date;
Qry.ExecSQL;
Qry.Open('SELECT * FROM employees');
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that any format settings for the date field in the underlying BindingSource / List / Adapter matches that of the form/grid field.  It might be that the underlying binding formatting for the field is overriding your new settings for the form/grid field.

Answer (score 1):

Set the format/display on your form field to "m/d/yyyy" **and for good measure**, *also do it through code in the `InitializeGrid` *event handler*

Answer (score 0):

This is happening b/c when the date format on your form field doesn't match that in SQLite3 which is "yyyy-mm-dd".  So you would need to set the format/display on your form field to match that.

Comment: I tried setting formatting for the column that displays the dates in the grid to yyyy-mm-dd as you suggested and it does not display them how I would like them. I want them to be displayed at m/d/yyyy (notice the forward slash as the separator) not as yyyy-mm-dd which is how they are displayed after your suggestion. I then changed the format for the column in the grid to m/d/yyyy and it now displays as m-d-yyyy until I close and reopen the app then it displays as m/d/yyyy which is the format I always want to be displayed.

Comment: Where did you set the formatting for the column exactly?  Look at the global settings for date formatting.

Comment: SQLite has no `DATE` data type.

Answer (score 0):

Uses DateUtils ...

DateUtils.DateOf(DateTimePicker1.Date);

Comment: That had zero effect. The format still stays at m-d-yyyy until I close and reopen the application. Then it changes to the desired result which is m/d/yyyy. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try

> FormatDateTime('dd/mm/yyyy', DateTimePicker1.Date);